# too many clients in postgresql in docker-swarm with spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, docker-swarm, hikaricp

I set up a development environment in docker swarm environment, which consists of 2 nodes, a few networks and a few microservices. Following gives an example how it looks in cluster.

```
Service                 Network               Node       Image Version

nginx reverse proxy     backend, frontend     node 1     latest stable-alpine
Service A               backend, database     node 2     8-jre-alpine
Service B               backend, database     node 2     8-jre-alpine
Service C               backend, database     node 1     8-jre-alpine
Database postgresql     database              node 1     latest alpine
```

Services are spring boot 2.1.7 applications with boot-data-jpa. All the services above contain database connection to postgresql instance. For database I configured only following properties in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url
spring.datasource.username
spring.datasource.password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

After some time I see that the connection limit in postgresql exceeds, which does not allow to create a new connection.

```
2019-09-21 13:01:07.031  1 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
```

A similar error is shown also when I try to connect over ssh to database.

```
psql: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

What I tried till now:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=20000
```

which didnt help.

I found several answers to this problem like:

- increase connection limit in postgresql

  No I dont want to do this. It is just a temporary solution. It will pollute the connection again but a bit later maybe.
- add idle timeout in hikaripCP configuration

  Default configuration of hikariCP has already a default value of 10mins, which doesnt help
- add max life time to hikariCP configuration

  Default configuration of hikariCP has already a default value of 30mins, which doesnt help
- reduce number of idle connection in hikariCP configuration

  Default configuration of hikariCP has already a default value of 10, which doesnt help
- set min idle in hikariCP configuration

  Default is 10 and I am fine with it. b

I am expecting a connection around 30 for the services but I find nearly 100 connections. Restarting the services or stopping them does not close the idle connections neither. What are your suggestions? Is it a docker specific problem? Did someone experience the same problem?